# MAKEFILE: no make 'core' is up to date

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm working on a school c++ project and i have to compile it with makefiles.

[I have this file architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OByMm.png)

this is my root Makefile

```
all :
    make -C core
    make -C lib

clean   :
    make -C core clean
    make -C lib clean

fclean  :
    make -C core fclean
    make -C lib fclean
    $(RM) arcade

re  :
    make -C core re
    make -C lib re

core    :
    make -C core

games   :
    make -C lib/games

graphicals  :
    make -C lib/graphicals
```

and my makefile of the core folder is

```
CC = g++

CPPFLAGS = -W -Wextra -Wall -Werror -ldl -g3

SDLFLAGS = -lSDL2

NCURSEFLAG = -lncurses

SFMLFLAG = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
COMMON_SRC = $(wildcard ../common/*.cpp)

OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
COMMON_OBJ = $(COMMON_SRC:.cpp=.o)

NAME = arcade

all :   $(NAME)
$(NAME) :   $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ)
        $(CC) $(OBJ) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(NAME)
        $(RM) $(COMMON_OBJ)
        cp $(NAME) ../

clean   :
    $(RM) $(OBJ)

fclean  : clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re  : fclean all
```

when i do `make` or `make games` or `make graphicals` it works perfectly but when i do `make core` i have this message `make: 'core' is up to date.` but when i go inside my core folder and i do a make it works.

Comment: `core` is the name of a file (directory) and `make` just sees that it already exists. Does it work if you make it phony (`.PHONY: core`)?

Comment: As a general rule you should never use `make` directly to invoke a recursive make; you should always use the `$(MAKE)` variable.  However, your problem is, as Biffen says, that `core` exists on the disk so when make checks to see if it's up to date, it succeeds (it exists and it has no prerequisites, so it's up to date).  You should use `.PHONY` for all "fake" targets, that aren't supposed to represent real files on the disk, to avoid exactly this problem.

Comment: OK, your answers helped me a lot.

Thank you.